# Unitary representation with fixed Casimir

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a connected reductive real Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. We denote by $\widehat{G}_u$ the unitary dual, that is the set of isomorphism classes of unitary reprensentation of $G$.

Let $C$ be the Casimir of $\mathfrak{g}$. It is in the center of the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$. Hence, it acts as a scalar $C_\pi\in \mathbf{C}$ on $\pi\in \widehat{G}_u$.

Is it true that  for a given $c\in \mathbf{C}$, there exits only finite $\pi\in \widehat{G}_u$ such that $C_\pi=c$?

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to saying that the Laplacian on $G$ doesn't have infinite dimensional eigenspaces?

Comment: Dear Joonas Ilmavirta, when $G$ is non compact, the Casimir is not elliptic. Only if restict to $C^\infty(G/K)$, Casimir is the Laplacian.

Comment: @shu: Treatments of infinitesimal characters related to unitary representations of real Lie groups usually involve the *complexified* Lie algebra and its universal enveloping algebra.   For a Casimir-type operator to act by a scalar may require an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @JimHumphreys, Thank you for the comment. I modified the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, for higher-rank groups, such as $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ with $n\ge 3$, it is straightforward to compute that the eigenvalue of Casimir on a unitary principal series is a quadratic polynomial in the parameters for the character, so there is a continuum of unitary principal series (generically irreducible) with the same eigenvalue of Casimir.

However Harish-Chandra proved that if the eigenvalues of *all* the center of the enveloping algebra are specified, there are only finitely-many irreducibles with those eigenvalues.

Edit: this is nearly a corollary of Harish-Chandra's sub-quotient theorem (and/or of Casselman's subrepresentation theorem), which asserts that irred admissibles are sub-quotients of principal series. The eigenvalues of the center of the enveloping algebra determine the principal series up to action of the Weyl group...

Comment: Could you give the reference of the Harish-Chandra's result? Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember which H-C paper it was, but probably you can find it by perusing Wallach's or Knapp's books on representation theory.